# CharField being shown as IntegerField in Database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

We're making a movie database application and using **Django 1.7** and **PostgreSQL**.

Here's what our `models.py` file looks like:

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lang = models.ForeignKey(Language, null=True)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, null=True)
    cast = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50))
```

To accommodate `ArrayField` we used

```
from djorm_pgarray.fields import ArrayField
from djorm_expressions.models import ExpressionManager
```

in out models.

And the following is the generated SQL for `cast`:

```
ALTER TABLE movies_movies ADD COLUMN "cast" integer[];
```

Any idea why the `cast` column turned out to be an integer even though we specified a `CharField`?

Comment: Side note: `"cast"` is a bad name for table column. It is a reserved word. Example: `cast('123' as integer)`

Comment: Noted. But the problem is something else. Changing `cast` to `castor` didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [djorm_pgarray docs](http://niwibe.github.io/djorm-pgarray/#_arrays_with_multiple_dimensions), you can create array of text as follows:

```
from djorm_pgarray.fields import TextArrayField

class Movies(models.Model):
    # ...
    cast = TextArrayField(dimension=1)
```

Or, according to [this](http://www.niwi.be/2012/10/07/postgresql-array-fields-with-django/) article:

```
from djorm_pgarray.fields import ArrayField

class Movies(models.Model):
    # ...
    cast = ArrayField(dbtype="text", dimension=1)
```

About `max_length` of text field (varchar and text are the same in fact to postgres): not sure, that it is possible to define it inside array in postgres.

Comment: Postgres copes fine with `varchar(50)[]` fields; setting the `dbtype` accordingly might be all it takes. But as you've pointed out, the string types are all the same under the hood, so unless your application logic actually requires the length constraint, you're probably better off with `text`.